# How to use a custom RemoteTokenServices in spring security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

Here is what I'm trying to achieve :

I want to use the DefaultSecurityFilterChain as it is but just use a custom RemoteTokenServices instead of the one provided by Spring.

Any idea how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create new class extends RemoteTokenServices, then you create 1 bean :

```
<bean id="tokenServices" class="ch.smartlink.wsc.util.CustomRemoteTokenServices">
    <property name="checkTokenEndpointUrl">
        <value>@{auth.host}#</value>
    </property>
    <property name="clientId">
        <value>@{auth.client.id}#</value>
    </property>
    <property name="clientSecret">
        <value>@{auth.client.secret}#</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Next step you need to inject tokenServices bean to :

```
    <oauth:resource-server id="resourceServer" token-services-ref="tokenServices" entry-point-ref="customAuthenticationEntryPoint"/>
```